# how to get proper path of a file while it gets uploaded

Tags: jsp, ubuntu, servlets

when I upload a file through jsp page, the servlet only shows filename it does not get whole file path when we run in ubuntu 14.04 through eclipse. How can we get complete path of a file

this is my partial code. i want get the whole path in fname in servlet

```
-----------------Servlet Code---------------------------
 /************************************************************/
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         String uname=session.getAttribute("username").toString();

        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            try 
            {
                String name=null,name1=null;
                String fname = null;
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for(FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if(!item.isFormField()) {
                        name=item.getName();
                        fname = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    }
                }
            }
        }       

    -----------------JSP code---------------------------
 /************************************************************/     
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form method="post" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload:
            <input type="text" name="username" value="${uname}"/>
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: will u share what u have done so will get to know where u want the filepath in servlet...

Answer (score 0):

```
 -----------------Servlet Code---------------------------
  /************************************************************/

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // checks if the request actually contains upload file
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     String uname=session.getAttribute("username").toString();

    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        try 
        {
            String name=null,name1=null;
            String fname = null;
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for(FileItem item : multiparts) {
                if(!item.isFormField()) {
                    name=item.getName();
                    fname = new File(item.getName()).getAbsolutePath();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

///now your fname will contain filepath in it

Comment: getAbsolutePath does not give the path where file is actually stored,instead it is giving the path where application is running.